# How can I merge results to a single dataframe after exctracting columns from different excel sheets?

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting columns from different excel files in a for loop and I want to merge the results to a single dataframe (concat).

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for excel in excels :
excel_df = pd.read_excel(excel)
extracted_columns = excel_df[[‚min', original_name]]

result = pd.concat(result , extracted_columns)          #? 
result.to_excel(‚summary.xlsx’)

result-liste in excel

extracted_columns
index   File1       (empty)                  File 2     (empty) .....
1    min values  original_name values     min values    original_name values
2    min values  origina_name values      min values    original_name values
```

How can I add the columns like in the psydocode line marked with #? to get an excel like in the lower part(extracted_columns) is equal for every file.

It would also be nice to add the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append DataFrames to list and then `concat`:

```
result = []
for excel in excels:
    #filter columns by usecols parameter
    excel_df = pd.read_excel(excel, usecols=['min', 'original_name'])
    #filter columns by lists
    excel_df = pd.read_excel(excel)[['min', 'original_name']]
```

Or:

```
result = [pd.read_excel(excel, usecols=['min', 'original_name']) for excel in excels]
result = [pd.read_excel(excel)[['min', 'original_name']] for excel in excels]
```

---

```
result = pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)          
result.to_excel('summary.xlsx', index=False)
```